# How to create a structure in a structure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, struct

In C code, I am trying to convert this (example):

```
typedef struct {
float a;
float b;
} Data

typedef struct {
int num;
Data datapts[100];
float x;
float y;
} Fulldata
```

What is the best way to convert this to MATLAB for intialization?

```
Fulldata = struct('num',0, *Insert Data structure here*, 'x',0,'y',0);
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Data = struct('a',0,'b',0);
Fulldata = struct('num',0,'datapts',Data,'x',0,'y',0);
```

Comment: Could also `repmat(Data, [1 100])` to match the `datapts[100]` in the example. Though a more idiomatic way would be to have Data store 1x100 arrays of doubles in its a and b fields.